# Reverse plone.app.linkintegrity IReferenceable check

Tags: plone

I have some pages with TinyMCE referencing some images.

Now, starting with the image objects I need to check what pages are reference my image, someone know how to make it?

I just find how to check into my pages what images are referenced, not the opposite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the `getBackReferences()` function of the `reference_catalog` tool; check the Plone [documentation on it](http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/content/archetypes/references.html).